# Unicode characters within VerbatimOut of fancyvrb

Tags: fancyvrb

Consider the following example, in which the sentence `Ceci est un résumé.` is written into the file `\jobname.mytmp` and then being read back.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.mytmp}
    Ceci est un résumé.
\end{VerbatimOut}

\input{\jobname.mytmp}

\end{document}
```

However, this cannot be compiled with `pdflatex`, as one would get `Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence`. Further investigation shows that `\jobname.mytmp` is not coded in UTF-8 but rather in "Windows 1252" (this is guessed by vscode, personally I don't know what this is). Is there a fix to this?

Comment: Is something stopping you from using either XeLaTeX or  LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @Mico Personally I usually use XeLaTeX. But this code is in a package that suppose to compile with any major TeX engine, so I'm looking for a fix for the pdfLaTeX case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fancyvrb` package uses `\immediate\write`, but this has the consequence that active characters not explicitly inactivated (such as `~`) are expanded.

If you patch the code to use a “protected” immediate write, it works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% define the same as \protected@write, but with \immediate
\providecommand*\protected@iwrite[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\thepage\relax
  #2%
  \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}\reserved@a
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
\patchcmd{\FVB@VerbatimOut}
  {\immediate\write\FV@OutFile}
  {\protected@iwrite\FV@OutFile{}}
  {}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.mytmp}
    Ceci est un résumé.
\end{VerbatimOut}

\input{\jobname.mytmp}

\end{document}
```

The contents of the written file is

```
    Ceci est un résumé.
```

Comment: Thank you for this! May I ask one question: will this patch possibly cause any other undesirable new errors in some case?

Comment: @Jinwen I don't think so, because macros are already “neutralized” because the backslash has been made a printable character.